# need help to understand the code

Tags: java, unix, shell-exec

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myshellScript.sh", "myArg1", "myArg2");
     Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
     env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
     env.remove("OTHERVAR");
     env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
     pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
     Process p = pb.start();
```

Help me in understanding the variables.
like (VAR1,myvalue),othervar,mydir

Comment: check [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class. You are building command which will be excuted on shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
pb.environment()
```

contains your environment variables for the current session. For this process to run you are adding and removing variables. When process.start() is called it will be able to use them

To quote the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

> an environment, which is a system-dependent mapping from variables to
>   values. The initial value is a copy of the environment of the current
>   process (see System.getenv()).

In general yoru code is running myshellScript.sh with arguments of MyArg1 and MyArg2 under a modified environment.